# Create Separate Firefox Audio Recordings Simultaneously

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, ffmpeg, audio-recording

For context, my overall intention is to create video and audio recordings of separate Firefox windows on the same machine.

I'm programmatically creating two instances of Firefox with different user profiles. The two Firefox windows are playing videos with audio. I'm currently using `pulseaudio` with the below command, where `USER` is a unique string, to configure the `pulseaudio` server:

```sh
pulseaudio -D --exit-idle-time=-1
pacmd load-module module-virtual-sink sink_name=${USER} # Load a virtual sink as ${USER}
pacmd set-default-sink ${USER} # Set ${USER} as the default sink device
pacmd set-default-source ${USER}.monitor # Set the monitor of the ${USER} sink to be the default source
```

This command runs before each Firefox window is created. Using `ffmpeg` as the encoder, I've been able to create videos that visually record only the Firefox window for which they were spawned, but the audio is overlapping when the windows are created concurrently. Below, I've edited down the `ffmpeg` command to contain the portion where I use `pulse`.

```sh
ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 2 -i default
```

What I'm wondering is: am I fundamentally misunderstanding something here, i.e., is it even possible to make independent audio recordings of Firefox windows while sound is playing simultaneously from either window?

If it is possible, please let me know if I should expand further on my implementation details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pavucontrol "playing"  tab  , you can unlock channel, then set   each Firefox instance  to a different channel (one left , one right) .
Then set the ffmpeg option -ac  to record only left or only right :
`ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 1 -i default testleft.mp4` 
`ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 2 -i default testright.mp4`
More flexible audio routing can be done by jackd but Firefox needs pulseaudio.
May be you can use [this](http://www.zamaudio.com/?p=1580) special Firefox with jackd support.

Comment: Thanks @laugeo this is a helpful idea. Regarding an implementation with `pulseaudio`, does this mean that the number of Firefox windows that could be recorded is limited by the number of audio channels?

Comment: IFAIK yes .   But using  using jack + pulseaudio at the same time  ,  you could use multiple normal Firefox , see https://askubuntu.com/questions/680817/jack-and-pulseaudio-multiple-sinks